Stacking two video or more layers in Adobe Premiere lags when playing preview
When stacking two video layers in my timeline, preview playback lags really bad.
My sequence settings all seem right, same frame rate.
If I render the timeline it works smoothly.
my raw footage is FHD 10bit, MOV file, codec H.264_422_longgop 100.
MY PC specs are: intel i7 14th, RTX 4070 12GB, 64GB RAM, SSD.
This happens randomly in the middle of editing the project. sometime wont happen at all.
Is this a normal behaviour? if so what can I do to solve this?
